# why the edgecolor is still there, when tedgecolor='none'

Tags: python, matplotlib

[the result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/883Nd.png)

```
rw=RandomWalk(5000)
rw.fill_walk()
plt.scatter(rw.x_values,rw.y_values,s=15)

#color the point as fading
point_numbers=list(range(rw.num_points))
plt.scatter(rw.x_values,rw.y_values,c=point_numbers,cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
    edgecolor='none',s=5)

#highlight the start and end point
plt.scatter(0,0,c='yellow',edgecolors='none',s=100)
plt.scatter(rw.x_values[-1],rw.y_values[-1],c='red',edgecolors='none',
    s=100)

plt.show()
```

I'm learning python matplotlib from book. I type the code as the book. While the points always have outline as **the result picture** shows, even when I set the edgecolor='none'.
 How did this happen? Could anyone tell me plz?

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing your points twice.

Once with a large size (`s=15`)

```
plt.scatter(rw.x_values,rw.y_values,s=15)
```

which does have an edgecolor (defaults to `rcParams["scatter.edgecolors"]`)

and then a second time with a smaller size (`s=5`)

```
plt.scatter(rw.x_values,rw.y_values,c=point_numbers,cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
    edgecolor='none',s=5)
```

The net effect is points with a edge and centered over them smaller points with a fading color